# Is it possible to customize the display of a webpart according to the membership group of the active directory on sharepoint server 2016?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

I would like to display a webpart component based on the membership group of the active directory. As in asp.net in C # with "[Authorize (Roles ="?

Comment: What webpart do you mean? Is it out-of-the-box webpart or custom one? What do you mean with "customize the displayof webpart"? Change how the data are rendered or hide whole webpart?

Comment: Depending on the connection display a webpart or not.